# how to put 2 gesture detections in the same line flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Good day , I would like to have two gesture detections on the same line, Problem is that when i run the app the two gesture detections are not on the same line but in separate lines which makes it look odd to user. How to make them be on same line just one on left and the other on right but same line

```
loginFields1() =>
          Container(
            child: Form(
                child: Column(
    
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
    
                    GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          //Navigate to Forgot Password Screen...
                          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage2()));
                        },
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: size.getWidthPx(180)),
                          child: Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                              child: Text("Validate Certificate",
                                  style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Exo2',fontSize: 14.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: colorCurve2))),
                        )),
                    GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          //Navigate to Forgot Password Screen...
                          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage3()));
                        },
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: size.getWidthPx(0)),
                          child: Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                              child: Text("Reset Password",
                                  style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Exo2',fontSize: 14.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: colorCurve2))),
                        )),
    
    
    
    
                  ],
                )),
          );
```

Comment: Maybe instead of `Column` use `Row` ?

Comment: instead of Gesture Detector, if you want to make Text function as a button just wrap it in  InkWell which has a lot of onTap properties

Comment: Solved it , Thank you, wish i could vote but you gave comment not solution

Answer (score -1):

So the problem is that you are using a column instead of a row. Just remove column and change it to row. This is how i use two gesture detectors.

Hope it helps :D